# Unable to send the XmlDocument as UTF-8 Encoded using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, xmlhttprequest

When I send this xml in c# - it gets sent as non UTF-8 formatted even though I have specified "UTF-8" both in the xml document declaration and in the HttpWebRequest.ContentType. How can I force it to send the data as UTF-8 ?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
XmlElement element1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "pacsoft", string.Empty);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(element1);
string destinationUrl = "";
Uri uri = new Uri(destinationUrl);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
byte[] bytes;
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"; 
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
return responseStr;
}
```

Comment: ContentType header does not have `encoding` parameter, this should be renamed to `charset`. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to change one line:

```
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
```

to

```
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestXml)
```

What you set in ContentType header is for server to know what encoding you want to accept for response.

Answer (score 0):

Found it : I need to change this line into:

```
 bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestXml);
```